# Make a card stretch to left slowly

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a div element with the class arrow-card inside the width there is another div with the class arrow-body it will make up a card so I want the card to grow width to the left slowly as soon as I click it
right to left with the transition.

```
.arrow-body{
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0,0,0,0.3);
width: 0px;
top: 130px;
position: relative;
display: none;
}


<div class="arrow-card">
<div class="arrow-body"></div>
</div>



if(window.getComputedStyle(arrow_body).
getPropertyValue("padding")==="0px"){

arrow_body.style.display = "initial";
arrow_body.style.transition = "0.2s";
arrow_body.style.width = "60px"
}else{
arrow_body.style.display = "none";
arrow_body.style.padding = "0px"
}
```

Comment: you want the `transition` as part of the CSS on that element all the time - adding a transition and a transitioning property won't transition

Comment: So what is the exact problem you have? Can you show what you are getting and instead what it shiuld be?

Comment: Also, when changing display:none to display:whatever, there is NO transition going to happen - you'll need to change the code to change the display mode, then in a setTimeout of 0 length, set the width - then you will get a transition

Comment: No everything is alright but my goal is to make that card to grow slowly to left not fast motion rather slow motion.

Comment: Show me that with code please I will be happy.

Comment: Also, you'll need to ensure that element has a **height**

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: if you change display from none -> initial, you won't get any transitions
Problem 2: the element has no height, so you won't see it anyway

Fix for 1: change the display to initial, add the transition, then in a setTimeout (of zero duration) change the width of the element

Fix for 2: give the element some **height** or some *content* which gives it **height**

```js
let arrow_body = document.querySelector('.arrow-body');

if (window.getComputedStyle(arrow_body).getPropertyValue("display") === "none") {
  arrow_body.style.display = "block";
  arrow_body.style.transition = "0.2s";
  setTimeout(() => arrow_body.style.width = "60px");
} else {
  arrow_body.style.display = "none";
  arrow_body.style.padding = "0px"
}
```

```css
.arrow-body {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 0px;
  top: 130px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-card">
  <div class="arrow-body">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My brother that's what I am talking about. thank you.

Comment: @YyuvAli - if I've helped, please consider accepting this answer